# YouTube API - advertisement on video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, ads

I've combed the youtube api documentation but still cannot find the answer to my question. I'm wondering whether there's a field/ or method in the youtube api, that will allow me to find out whether a specific video has an advertisement (or what type of advertisement) on it?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Any solution on this?

Answer (score 2):

In [video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource), there's an item called "`contentDetails.licensedContent`", where you can find if the video is claimed by content owners (YouTube Partners), and that is one of the condition if ads will show up.

Important thing is that the type of ads would be determined on "runtime" and we can't get them through API beforehand.